# Corrupted data when using a multidimensional char array

Tags: c, sorting, external-sorting

I'm currently implementing a function to use the "external sort" method because I have to sort a big file (+200K lines) on a device with low RAM, right now just trying to make it run on a windows pc.
I'm working on the function to split the file in tiny sorted files.

The problem I'm facing is that among the tiny sorted files the function creates, the data on certain lines are truncated.

I'm quite sure I've done a mistake somewhere but was not able to find it, yet. Could you help me to discover the problem please ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 50
#define MAX_LINES_SORTED 130

void createSortedFiles(FILE*);

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\C\\Tests\\1.txt", "r+");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error opening fp");
        return 1;
    }

    createSortedFiles(fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return strcmp(p1, p2);
}

void createSortedFiles(FILE* fp) {
    FILE* sfp;
    //FILE* sfp2 = fopen("C:\\C\\Tests\\test.txt", "w+");
    char lines[MAX_LINES_SORTED][MAX_LINE_LEN + 1] = {0}, buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN + 1] = { 0 }, fnum[6];
    char fname[20] = "C:\\C\\Tests\\";
    char *p;
    int i = 0, j = 0 /*file names*/, int max_lines = MAX_LINES_SORTED - 1;
    size_t N;

    while (1){
        p = fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp);
        // fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, sfp2);

        if(strlen(buffer) > 0 || i > 0){
            if(p != NULL)
                memcpy(lines[i], buffer, strlen(buffer));


            //If reached the max number of lines accepted in the array
            //Or reached EOF
            //=> Sort and write the array "lines"
            if (i >= max_lines || p == NULL) {
                N = sizeof(lines) / sizeof(lines[0]);
                qsort(lines, N, sizeof(*lines), cmp);

                //sets the name of the current file
                memset(&fname[11], 0, 9);
                itoa(j, fnum, 10);
                strcat(fname, fnum);

                if ((sfp = fopen(fname, "w+")) == NULL) {
                    printf("Error opening sfp");
                    return;
                }

                for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    fwrite(lines[i], strlen(lines[i]), 1, sfp);
                }

                fclose(sfp);

                memset(lines, 0, sizeof(lines[0][0]) * MAX_LINES_SORTED * MAX_LINE_LEN);

                j++; i = -1; //because incremented right after
            }
        }

        if(p == NULL){
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    //fclose(sfp2);

    return;
}
```

Here's an example of the fp file (each lines ending with `\r\n`):

```
8023796280724;00060-014.W47
8023796280731;00060-014.W48
;0009070305/08007
;0009470337/08007
;0009490338/13001
;0010480311/08007
;0010830308/08007
;0011S
8033280129293;002004GRS4XL
;002015RSM
5708628117005;00207-630-06T42
5708628117012;00207-630-06T44
5708628117036;00207-630-06T46
4051428088756;647530241000045
4051428088763;647530241000046
4051428088770;647530241000047
;647BLPMF
4051428092586;648510256000040
4051428092593;648510256000041
4051428092609;648510256000042
4051428092616;648510256000043
4051428092623;648510256000044
4051428092630;648510256000045
4051428092647;648510256000046
```

Comment: `char lines[MAX_LINES_SORTED][MAX_LINE_LEN + 1] = {0}, buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN + 1], *p, fname[20] = "C:\\C\\Tests\\", fnum[6];`?  ***ALL*** on one line?  That's pretty much unreadable.  Cramming as much code into one line as possible just makes for hard-to-read code and bugs.

Comment: Noted, sorry about the readability, I corrected it

Comment: `p = fgets(buffer, ...);` Once everything else works, remember to check the return value `p` *before* attempting to use `buffer`.

Comment: Did you read [*Introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) ? Take several days to read that book. Then read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/).

Comment: The next week, read the documentation of your C compiler (e.g [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Invoke GCC with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Use [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) to read the documentation of *every function* you did not define (e.g. of [fopen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)...) and use your debugger to understand the behavior of your program.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for your recommandations, no I didn't read those books but I sure will take a look at them.  I dug more and found what was wrong

Comment: Aside: `itoa(j, fnum, 10);` is _only_ good up to `j <= 99,999,999`, else buffer overflow.  Not a great concern  as `j` unlikely to be so large, yet consider a buffer than handles all possible `itoa()` results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "truncated lines" are not really truncated lines, they are stray data left in the buffer from previous files.

This array:

```
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 50
#define MAX_LINES_SORTED 130

char lines[MAX_LINES_SORTED][MAX_LINE_LEN + 1];
```

has 6630 bytes, but here:

```
memset(lines, 0, sizeof(lines[0][0]) * MAX_LINES_SORTED * MAX_LINE_LEN);
```

you zero out only 6500 bytes and leave the last two lines as they are.

You can fix this by using `(MAX_LINE_LEN +1)` in the size calculation, but the array can be zeroes out more tersely (and more reliably) with just:

```
memset(lines, 0, sizeof(lines));
```

Comment: Thank you, Indeed now that I see it makes sense, I don't know why I thought by using `MAX_LINE_LEN` instead of `MAX_LINE_LEN + 1` it will just not initialize to 0 the last bytes of each lines in my array, but instead it didn't reset the last lines of my array if I understand correctly

Comment: Yes, you missed out on the two lines that start at bytes 6528 and 6579. It's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: (There's another issue: when you check whether `i >= 130`, you have already copied the buffer into `lines[130]`, which is one beyond the end of the array. It will corrupt memory (perhaps only `buffer`) and wil make you lose every 131th line of input.)

Comment: Yeah I found out about it a few mins ago, that was why the program was acting so randomly. Everything is good now I believe